# Java Regex html parser

Tags: java, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [java regex quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9206735/java-regex-quantifiers)

I am learning some regex right now, and Im having trouble with this problem:

So I have a string like
TAG1 sometext TAG2 some text TAG3 someText

What I need to get are the sub-strings between the tag statements. something like

```
Tag1 sometext
Tag2 some text
Tag3 someText
```

so I wrote this regex,

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("TAG\\d.*TAG\\d");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while(matcher.find){
    print(matcher.group);
}
```

But the output is

```
TAG1 sometext TAG2 some text TAG3 someText
```

The way I understand it is, dot matches anything and star quantifies that to none or many. Since I believe my regex to mean
TAG with some number then some other stuff then TAG and some number.

I am also realizing while I write this, that I do not want all subsets of 
TAG# text TAG#
combinations. 
for example I do not want
TAG# text TAG# text TAG#

can someone augment my understanding of regex please?

Thanks

EDIT ---

I am not writing a full blown html parser in regex. no.
This is an html parsing project and I am using Jsoup for the biggest part of it.
This regex is just a hack to get some meta data about the html so that I pass the html to jsoup in one form or another.

Comment: Regex is a two sided sword, use a HTML Parser instead, like http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/

Comment: [You shouldn't try to parse HTML with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1733489/720003

Comment: this is the answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9206766/720003

Answer (score 1):

There is no group in your expression. Split them into groups using paranthesis. Like "(TAG\d)(.*)(TAG\d)" I am alos novice with regex, you might need to play with your regex but at least the paranthesis part is bare minimum.

Comment: I tried this, but it had the same result. just for learnings sake, how would one match a '(' then? thanks for the answer anyway.

Comment: backslash or escape that like this (\( or \\ or \n etc etc) but it didnt work? Must be java specific regex engine anomaly...  i mean there might be other way to do that. You want to get this exericse one time only or build an application using regex cause if former I might suggest you to use better regex tools.

Comment: You'll want to add a group if you don't want to see the TAG part in the output: `TAG\d(.*)`, but see my answer about limiting what you're matching.  Any time you want to match a special character as a literal, just add an escape: `\\(` will match a left parenthesis.

Comment: And on top of all these.. writing a full blown HTML parser in regex is very big and very tough exercise. Regex limitation will hit you.

Answer (score 1):

Regex quantifiers are greedy by default - they will match as much as possible, so `.*` matches all the following TAG# sequences.  Explanation of how to add appropriate modifiers [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html).

You may also find [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to be useful.

Also, why is this tagged HTML? Doesn't seem like that's what you're parsing.

Comment: ah you are right, it shouldn't be tagged as such. Its part of an html parsing project though, and my brain was on auto pilot...

Comment: Just to echo @Nishant then, parsing HTML with regex is a hideous undertaking and should only be done for educational purposes. I've had good experience with the [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) parser.