# java regex quantifiers

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like

```
String string = "number0 foobar number1 foofoo number2 bar bar bar bar number3 foobar";
```

I need a regex to give me the following output:

```
number0 foobar
number1 foofoo
number2 bar bar bar bar
number3 foobar
```

I have tried

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("number\\d+(.*)(number\\d+)?");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

but this gives

```
number0 foobar number1 foofoo number2 bar bar bar bar number3 foobar
```

Comment: Can there be newlines in your string?

Comment: yes, I had to add Pattern.DOTALL and it works. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you want `number` (+ an integer) followed by anything until the next `number` (or end of string), right?

Then you need to tell that to the regex engine:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("number\\d+(?:(?!number).)*");
```

In your regex, the `.*` matched as much as it could - everything until the end of the string. Also, you made the second part `(number\\d+)?` part of the match itself.

**Explanation of my solution:**

```
number    # Match "number"
\d+       # Match one of more digits
(?:       # Match...
 (?!      #  (as long as we're not right at the start of the text
  number  #   "number"
 )        #  )
 .        # any character
)*        # Repeat as needed.
```

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker, thanks for the answer! I always enjoy reading your detailed explanations.

Answer (score 0):

because `.*` is a greedy pattern. use `.*?` instead of `.*`

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("number\\d+(.*?)(number\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
while(matcher.find();){
    out(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: That isn't going to work - this matches only `number0`, `number1`, `number2` and `number3`. The second group is optional (and it shouldn't be part of the match anyway.

Comment: It still doesn't match the right content. The results for the test string are `number0 foobar number1` and `number2 bar bar bar bar number3`. Didn't you test your code? (It also fails if there is an odd number of `number`s in the string.)

Answer (score 0):

If "foobar" is just an example and really you mean "any word" use the following pattern: `(number\\d+)\s+(\\w+)`

Comment: That fails on `number2 bar bar bar bar`.

Comment: Right. I did not pay attention on multiple `bar`. But it is not a problem to fix: (number\\d+)(?:\s+(\\w+))+

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just match for `number\\d+`, query the match location, and do the String splitting yourself?

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\w+\\d(\\s\\w+)\1*");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```

Comment: Nice use of the [backreference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)! However, this will not work when trying to match "number4 bar foo bar", which might be what the OP is aiming for (in that case "number4 bar" is returned instead of "number4 bar foo bar").

Answer (score -1):

`(.*)` part of your regex is greedy, therefore it eats everything from that point to the end of the string. Change to non-greedy variant: `(.*)?`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Comment: That isn't going to work - this matches only `number0`, `number1`, `number2` and `number3`.